# Timesheet reporting in FogBugz?

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-on-demand

Currently it's a big PITA to create timesheet report for say a week or month in FogBugz... maybe someone knows about a plugin to that for you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is kind of old so I am assuming you were using FB6, but if you are now using FB7 to do exactly this: [ClarkKent](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/Plugins/plugin.aspx?ixPlugin=10).

Comment: except that ClarkKent returns your hours in minutes instead of hours. huge fail, IMO.

Comment: @Jason - Ever consider contacting the plugin author about that? I'm sure they would welcome the feedback.

Comment: Came across ClarkKent on my own before I saw this answer, and it does work quite well. We came across it a bit too late though :) By the time I found it we already built our own solution using FogBugz API. Maybe we should opensource it if there is a demand for it... Just need to get my act together and see how to publish your own plugins for FB.

Comment: Actually, it is pretty simple. I've published a number of them. Just go to the plug-in gallery and set up an account then upload it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have FogBugz hosted on your own server, you can query the database manually and get timesheet results that way. If its hosted by FogBugz, then you can download the database, do the same query, or, use the API to get all the time entries. Some programs already exists for that, one of them is TimeSprite, but its not free.